# Passing a string in onclick function's in for loop

Tags: javascript, html

I need to pass string as ID in `onclick` function. When I pass integer as id, it's working fine but when I pass string, it's not even going to the function.

HTML Code ( below is table row. This is inside a for loop)

```
<td class="col-md-2" width="50" style="background-color: transparent;">
<input class="btn btn-sm btn-primary fa" id='iedit-@item.ID' type="button" value="&#xf040" onclick='showedit(@item.ID);' />
</td>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function showedit(par) {
        if (editItem == par) {
            return;
        }
        if (editItem > 0) {
            cancel(editItem);
        }

       --code processing--
        editItem = par;
    }
```

The above code works fine if there is integer value in `item.Id`. But when I change the HTML code to have string value in `item.Id`, nothing happens. It isn't even going to the function (checked by putting breakpoint).

HTML Code- with item.ID as string `***the below isn't working***`

```
<td class="col-md-2" width="50" style="background-color: transparent;">
<input class="btn btn-sm btn-primary fa" id='iedit-\"" +@item.ID +"\"' type="button" value="&#xf040" onclick='showedit(\"" +@item.ID+ "\");' />
</td>
```

I searched and tried couple of similar options but nothing seem to be working for me. Please advise.

Comment: Thanks. But I am very new to all this and this is my first project involving JS & HTML. Unfortunately never used jsfiddle. After your comment I am trying to use jsfiddle. Gmme some time to try and post back. Thanks

Comment: see @lukbl answer in which quotes are added to the showedit() parameter. Missing quotes in your code seems the mostly likely problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using asp.net mvc on server?

```
 <td class="col-md-2" width="50" style="background-color: transparent;">
<input class="btn btn-sm btn-primary fa" id='iedit-@item.ID' type="button" value="&#xf040"  onclick='showedit("@(item.ID)");' />
</td>
```

Also notice that `id` of an `input` will be different than `item.ID` which you are passing to function - it is prefixed with "iedit" - make sure that does not cause any problems in your function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I am using asp.net mvc. This worked. Was struggling for last 3-4 hours. Will check the other point too. Thanks again for everything.